# How to change string from another file

Tags: c#, winforms, integer

So I have two forms, one is called Form1 and one is called Form2. In one of the files of the forms I have a integer called 'peopleNum'. On Form1 there is a button that opens Form2. On Form2 there is a textbox and a button. When the user presses the button on Form2 I want 'peopleNum' to be equal to that textbox.

This is the code I am 'trying' to do to further explain this

```
//Form1 (global variable)
int peopleNum = 0;

//Form2
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        peopleNum = peopleNumIn.Text;
        this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you could make the `int` in `Form1` `public`, so it would look like this:

```
public int peopleNum = 0;
```

As for setting it from `Form2`, the way I would do it is add a `Form1` parameter to the `Form2` constructor. This way you can access the public integer from the calling form.

You are also going to want a private instance of `Form1` inside of your `Form2` class.

If this is confusing, let me explain everything in code.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 parent;

    public Form2(Form1 parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        parent.peopleNum = Convert.ToInt32(peopleNumIn.Text);
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that with this method, you need to pass the calling form whenever you create a new instance of `Form2`

Let me show you in code:

```
void ShowForm2()
{
    var form2 = new Form2(this);
    form2.Show();
}
```

Comment: I get an unhandled error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @OMGOMG132 Where are you getting that exception?

Comment: no where. It says StackOverFlowException was unhandled. And one of the tips was to make sure there were no infinite loops...

Answer (score 0):

Form2 should expose the contents of that TextBox via a property.  Keep in mind that the property should be type `int`, so you must incorporate validation and conversion.  Form1 can then retrieve that property value from Form2.  You might do that when Form2 closes if it's a modal dialogue or when an event is raised otherwise.

Check out my blog post here for information on communicating between forms.  The third part explains the "proper" way to do it.

http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/managing-data-among-multiple-forms-part.html